# 'htop' process and threads cpu usage?

Tags: process, htop, thread

I'm observing a multi threaded process in htop in tree view. If I were to strip it just to the problematic part, it looks somewhat like this:

```
                  CPU%
 bin/process       100
  `- thread1        70
  `- thread2         0
```

The process all together is using 100% and one of the threads is using 70%. Where do I place the other 30%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`thread1` and `thread2` are child threads spawned by the main process but the main process can still do work.

In your output of htop `bin/process` (and all child threads) are using 100% of cpu. 70% of the cpu is used by `thread1` and 0% by `thread2`, the remaining (difference) is the main process that spawn/manages these child threads.

Answer (score -2):

The 1st coloumn of the same row(at the extreme left) of the thread it will show the ID of the thread. `grep` that thread ID in the output of `ps -eLf` and you will see the thread.

Remember, you have to use the options `-eLF` to include the threads in the output.

From `man ps` :

```
 -L              Show threads, possibly with LWP and NLWP columns
```

Comment: completely irrelevant to question